# Laravel 3 / Eloquent ORM : Models extending other models

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm writing a simple app in Laravel 3 and I have 2 models: Item and PeculiarItem.

PeculiarItem should "extend" Item by simply adding additional fields (say, "color", "price", etc.).

The idea is that I can keep the "core" class Item for common stuff (say, "precedence" or "title") and just extend it for different kinds of items each with their own peculiar set of fields.

```
    class Item extends Eloquent
    {
        // Just a simple model with a couple relationship with other models, such as Page, Collection 

        public static $table = 'items';

        public function page()
        {
        return $this->belongs_to('Page');
        }

        public function collection()
        {
        return $this->belongs_to('Collection');
        }
    }

// ...

class PeculiarItem extends Item 
{
    public static $table = 'peculiar_items';
    // Ideally this PeculiarItem needn't redeclare the page_id and collection_id foreign key fields
    // because it extends Item. 

}
```

The problems comes from the way ORM is hard-wired when calling the save() method on my PeculiarItem objects.

```
// ...

class Item_Controller extends Base_Controller
{

    /**
     * @param   $type   the class name of the object we are creating
     * @param   $data   the data for the new object
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function action_create($type = null, $data = null)
    {
        // ... filter, validate data, etc.
        $entry = new $type($data);
        $entry->save();
    }
}

// ...
```

Example POST request: item/create/peculiaritem

data: page_id = 1, collection_id = 1, title = 'Foo', ...

This fails because PeculiarItem does not have fields page_id or collection_id.

How can I get around this situation?
Is it a bad idea in principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot and should not do this since `peculiar_items` is its own table.

With that said, in your Eloquent models, you setup the relations with `->has_one`, `->has_many`, and `->belongs_to` methods. From there, you would then be able to use `Item::find()->peculiar_item()->first()->someSpecialProperty`, etc... (untested).

Since I've been using L4, it's hard for me to remember the setup for L3 - they use snake case. Check this out: http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Imagine if I had 15 different classes extending Item. Should I then have to create 15 different ways to handle object creation inside the Item_Controller, then?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Eloquent is smart. You're able to `Item::find(123)->peculiar_items()->get()` - which would return all peculiar items related to the parent item. This relationship would be setup in your `Item` model, method `peculiar_items() { return $this->has_many('peculiar_items', 'parent_key_name'); }`

Comment: After reading my questions I might have realized the situation is not clear enough, so here's another attempt.

What if you wanted to create an API that let you add several kinds of items but keeping the models / tables DRY? Imagine that ALL items have certain common features (precedence, title, etc) but every item kind has its own specific features (color / weight, any possible combination). My goal would be to have a single API call like "create/item" that gets all the data at once and instantiates the correct kind of Item class.

Comment: Eloquent still does this for you when you call the models methods. We'd really have to see a real-world case example if we're wrong.

Comment: Thank you, while your comments weren't exactly proposing a solution they actually helped me see what was wrong in my approach: i will create a model for each kind of "item" and let them extend a common abstract class Item, but still have the database structure be un-DRY (meaning I will have to repeat the common fields there). I know it sounds a bit ugly, but in my use-case this is what makes most sense I suppose.